# sed search and replace last field of a line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

is there a way using sed and awk to search for every last (by spaces seperated) field of a line (in a file), matching a search value (without touching the other fields even if string is matched in a field before the last one), and can that searched value be changed with an other value?

```
210983342900 342832423-1 i2301rw1900 309212dw90 900
9328423ABC 32091840-943543-9435 3012=32193900 301 3029432 334
210983342900ABCDE 342832423-1 i2301rw1900 309212dw90 900
9328423 32091840-943ABC3-9435 3012=32193900 301 3029432 ABC
3843209898 48435843098543098543 43985439859209438543 499 ABC
```

So search for ABC at every last field, and change every found value to DEFG
or search for 900 at every last field and change it to 000

Can you guys break down and explain the solution?

Comment: An example would be fine ?

Comment: Do you want a regexp or string match? Full or partial match? Do you care about retaining exact white space between fields? [edit] your question to show more useful sample input (e.g. if you wanted to match "A.C"  then include "ABC", "A.CD", etc. in the example to demonstrate behavior when regexp and/or partial matching can occur) and the expected output given that input.

Comment: Please, provide an example of some original text and also a literal example of the output desired for that example. Use an example that illustrates what needs to be done and also what must not be done

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'This is terrible, I feel terrible' | awk '{if ($NF~"^terri") $NF="good"; print}'
```

This will do that.

`$NF` is the field at position `NF`. In `awk` this is the number of fields, so it is the last field.

`$NF~"^terri"` uses the `~` to match a regular expression. You can use `==` if you want an exact match.

`$NF="good"` will replace the field, but only if the `if` condition is met.

Finally `print` prints the whole record.

```
echo '
    210983342900 342832423-1 i2301rw1900 309212dw90 900
9328423ABC 32091840-943543-9435 3012=32193900 301 3029432 334
210983342900ABCDE 342832423-1 i2301rw1900 309212dw90 900
9328423 32091840-943ABC3-9435 3012=32193900 301 3029432 ABC
3843209898 48435843098543098543 43985439859209438543 499 ABC
' | awk '{if ($NF=="ABC") $NF="DEFG"; print}'
```

Comment: Please, give me some time later to format a little bit the answer.  This is just to give you a hint in the meantime...

Comment: We don't even know what the question is yet,,, Maybe `/ABC/` or `index($0,"ABC")` or `/^ABC/` or `/ABC$/` or `index($0,"ABC")==1` for the search part is needed and maybe `$NF=="foo"` or `sub(/\S+$/,""); $0=$0 "foo"` or something else for the replacement. There are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/([[:blank:]]+)ABC$/\1whatever/' infile
```

- `-E` enables extended-regular-expression , so we no need to escape `(`,`)` or `+` here.
- `[:blank:]` matches Space or tab characters only
- `[[:blank:]]` character class in regular expression is valid only inside the brackets of a character list.
- `[[:blank:]]+` matches one-or-more Space or Tabs characters
- `(...)` parentheses create a group match and `\1` would be its back-reference for first group; `\2` for second, `\3` for third and up-to `\9` for ninth group; we have only defined one group match.
- `ABC` matches exactly `ABC` string.
- `$` is the end of line anchor
- in replacement part we return back the first group match with `\1`; this is used to preserve any whitespaces before string `ABC` and that will be replaces with `whatever` string.

---

to replace last field with `whatever`:

```
sed -E 's/([[:blank:]]+)[^[:blank:]]*$/\1whatever/' infile
```

you noticed the `^` inside the bracket in `[^[:blank:]]`? that's negation character if it comes in character-class and at first, so given character-class will match any character except Space or Tabs. note that string `whatever` will append to the end of line if line was ending with trailing whitespaces since of used `*` quantifier in `[^[...]]*` known as zero-or-more of characters. change it to `[^[:blank:]]+` if you don't want that happen.